# Создание плагинов jQuery

Tags: jquery, плагин

Добрый день

Уже немало работаю с jQuery. Но вот возникает периодически вопрос по созданию плагинов. А именно вопрос касательно событий.

Если, скажем, у нас есть пример:

```
test= function(options) {

  this.init(options);

};

$.extend(test.prototype, {
  init: function() {

    }
});
```

Вопрос: если в методе `init` и выберу `DOM` элемент и назначу ему событие `click`. Т.е. есть ли приемлемый способ, чтобы обработчиком этого события был метод объекта `test`, и чтобы сохранился инициализированный объект? Чтобы через `this` мне были доступны методы `test` и все его свойства.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для этой цели есть `jQuery.proxy`:

```
var test = function(options) {
    this.init(options);
}
$.extend(test.prototype, {

    field: 'hello world',
    init: function(options) {
         $(options).click($.proxy(this.handler, this));
    },
    handler: function() {
         alert(this.field);
    }

});

$(function() {

    var t = new test('#myButton');

});
```

Документация: [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)